# Javascript not running when triggered by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I have an html form in with a drop down menu and a series of checkboxes. The dropdown has two options. Each option is supposed to check several of the checkboxes using javascript with an onchange event within the "select" tag. This works 100%, but it fails when I trigger it with more javascript.
I have narrowed it down to the part where is resets all the checkboxes to be unchecked. It is then supposed to select the boxes it needs based on the drop down, but because it fails to uncheck them all, they all remain checked. 
Here is the code:

select box:

```
<select name='myrp_autogroups' id='myrp_autogroups' onchange='myrp_group_selector();'>
  <option></option>

<?php
  $presets = get_option("myrp_presets");
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($presets); $i++) {
  $preset = $presets[$i];
  echo "<option value='";
  for ($b = 0; $b < count($preset[1]); $b++) {
    $checkbox = $preset[1][$b];
    echo $checkbox . ",";
  }
  echo "'";
  echo ">" . $preset[0] . "</option>";
}

update_option("myrp_presets", $presets);
?>
</select>
<input type="button" value="change" onclick="change_group();">
<script  type='text/javascript'>
    window.onload = change_group();
</script>
```

Javascript:

```
function myrp_group_selector()
{
  // reset everything.
  $mrjQ(".myrp_checkboxes").each(function() {
    var name = this.id.split("myrp_c_");

    if(name.length == 2) {
      document.getElementById("myrp_value_" + name[1]).disabled=true;
      document.getElementById("myrp_value_" + name[1]).value="";

      this.checked=false;
    }
  });
  if(document.getElementById("myrp_average_top") != null)
  {
    document.getElementById("myrp_average_top").checked=false;
    document.getElementById("myrp_average_value_top").value="";
  }

  if(document.getElementById("myrp_average_bottom") != null)
  {
    document.getElementById("myrp_average_value_bottom").value="";
    document.getElementById("myrp_average_bottom").checked=false;
  }

  var checkThese = document.getElementById("myrp_autogroups")[document.getElementById("myrp_autogroups").selectedIndex].value;
  var checkArray = checkThese.split(",");
  var average = "avg";

  // check the new stuff
  for(var i in checkArray)
  {
    if(checkArray[i] == average)
    {
      if(document.getElementById("myrp_average_top") != null)
      {
        document.getElementById("myrp_average_top").checked=true;
      }

      if(document.getElementById("myrp_average_bottom") != null)
      {
        document.getElementById("myrp_average_bottom").checked=true;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById("myrp_c_"+checkArray[i]).checked=true;
      document.getElementById("myrp_value_"+checkArray[i]).disabled=false;
    }
  }

}
function change_group() {
    select = document.getElementById('myrp_autogroups');
    if(select.value != '2,3,4,5,6,'){
        select.value = '2,3,4,5,6,';
        select.onchange();
        }
}
```

I have narrowed it down to this section, keep in mind it functions perfectly if i manually select an option from the dropdown and doesn't work when triggered by java:

```
// reset everything.
  $mrjQ(".myrp_checkboxes").each(function() {
    var name = this.id.split("myrp_c_");

    if(name.length == 2) {
      document.getElementById("myrp_value_" + name[1]).disabled=true;
      document.getElementById("myrp_value_" + name[1]).value="";

      this.checked=false;
    }
  });
```

Comment: You mean when you fire it here? `select.onchange();`. You getting any console errors?

Comment: I have verified that it does trigger the onchange event, just not that specific section of the javascript function.

Comment: FYI, `window.onload = change_group();` should be `window.onload = change_group;`

Comment: hahah.. and thats all it was. OMG. We'll put this in the Over Thinking It category. Feel free to put it as an answer and i'll chalk it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the wrong is :

```
window.onload = change_group() ;
```

it should be

```
window.onload = change_group;
```

Comment: credit will be given to cookie monster if he so chooses to answer.

Comment: hhhhhhh what you mean buddy ?

Comment: @GarettCosco: I'm not going to answer. I usually just post comments and let others gain the rep, so don't let an answer in a comment slow you down. :-)